# Array of JSON from fetch

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

After making a fetch request to an api, the response is an array of JSONs, like so:

`[ {"key":"val", "k2":"v2"}, {"k3":"v3", "k4":"v4"} ]`

So far I am trying to handle this by doing `response => response.text()`

Is there any efficient method to parse this array into separate JSONs, other than tediously parsing it as one big string?

Comment: The response object has a built in `json()` method  ... `response => response.json()`

Comment: Is the returned response already an array? What do you mean by parsing it and what's your intended result?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [body.json() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

```
response.json().then(function(data) {
  // do something with your data
});
```